# SQL subsetting after a first subsetting

Tags: sql

I have a table called Mytable like this:

| Code | Date | Name1 | Name 2 | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 2022-03-14 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 4 |
| ABC123 | 2022-03-14 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 5 |
| ABC123 | 2022-03-13 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 4 |
| ABC123 | 2022-03-13 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 5 |
| ABC456 | 2021-12-31 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 4 |
| ABC456 | 2021-12-31 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 5 |
| ABC456 | 2021-03-13 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 4 |
| ABC456 | 2021-03-13 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 5 |
| DEF123 | 2022-03-13 | OtherName1 | OtherName2 | 4 |
| DEF123 | 2022-03-14 | OtherName1 | OtherName2 | 5 |

I want to get only this rows:

| Code | Date | Name1 | Name 2 | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 2022-03-14 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 4 |
| ABC123 | 2022-03-14 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 5 |
| ABC456 | 2021-12-31 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 4 |
| ABC456 | 2021-12-31 | Myname1 | Myname2 | 5 |

That is, I want to subset the rows with Name1=Myname1 and Name2= Myname2:

```
SELECT * FROM Mytable WHERE Name1='Myname1' AND Name2='Myname2'
```

But I don't want all of them. I need only the rows with the most recent dates for each Code. Each code has a different most recent date. I think that I can get the most recent date for each code with:

```
SELECT Code, MAX(Date) FROM Mytable WHERE Name1='Myname1' AND Name2='Myname2' GROUP BY Code
```

But I don't know how to combine this two subsettings in one query, since adding the rest of the column names to the last query doesn't work:

```
SELECT Name1, Name2, Code, MAX(Date) FROM Mytable WHERE Name1='Myname1' AND Name2='Myname2' GROUP BY Code
```

Thanks!!

Comment: You can use a CTE to get the most recent date for each code, then join to that CTE on code and date.

Comment: Thanks @Isolated I just learnt what is a CTE. Found an example that should work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Code, [Date], Name1, Name2, Price
FROM (
    SELECT *, dense_rank() over (partition by code order by code, [date] desc) rn
    FROM [Mytable]
    WHERE Name1='Myname1' AND Name2='Myname2'
) T 
WHERE rn = 1
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66c6ec98a906a8a49ac5e55e1d1a6ac2

Comment: So basically this ranks the returned rows in by their `Date` within each `Code`. I never bothered to learn why `rank` was useful until now — thanks for this instructive answer

Comment: Thanks Joel! Many new things to learn in your answer! I get an error in my data base. It doesn't like the "["   "ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:undefined: SELECT cod_tnumgroup, [dat_calculo], co... ^ Encountered: [ Expected: CASE, CAST, DEFAULT, EXISTS, FALSE, IF, INTERVAL, LEFT, NOT, NULL, REPLACE, RIGHT, TRUNCATE, TRUE, IDENTIFIER CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

Comment: Deleting the brackets seems to work fine. Thanks!

Comment: The brackets are how Sql Server lets you use reserved words like `Date` as table and column names. If you don't tag which specific database you've got in the question, we're free to pick which one we're more comfortable, leaving you to need to decode that kind of thing. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I never really use `partition` (out of ignorance) so I'd probably just write this. The optimizer should make this run fast enough and it's super easy to understand.

```sql
SELECT Code, Date, Name1, Name2, Price
FROM Mytable t1
WHERE Date IN (
  SELECT MAX(t2.Date)
  FROM Mytable t2
  WHERE t1.Code = t2.Code
)
AND Name1 = 'Myname1'
AND Name2 = 'Myname2'
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work in my database: AnalysisException: Unsupported correlated subquery with grouping and/or aggregation

Comment: Whoops, needed to be `MAX(t2.Date)` I think.  fixed.

Comment: Just googling the error... is this an Impala database?

Comment: You might have to refactor this into a self-join... IDK what Impala supports. I think this query should work in alternatives like hive, BigQuery, etc for sure. It's definitely valid SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Name1 & Name2 to group by

```
SELECT 
  Name1, 
  Name2, 
  Code, 
  MAX(Date) AS "Date",
  Price
FROM Mytable 
WHERE Name1='Myname1' 
AND Name2='Myname2' 
GROUP BY Code, Name1, Name2
```

Comment: This does not have the column `Price` and it's not so trivial to change the query to add it.

Comment: I don't think this will compile now because Price is not grouped or aggregated.